# Remove all <div> with the following classes that are inside the container <div>

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to remove all existing `<div>s` with classes `flag`, `edit`, `delete`, that are inside a `div` `container`. What is the right way to do it? Somehow, what ever I do just wont work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar poll thingy</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
    $("#container").remove('.flag, .edit, .delete');
    $(this).parent("div").after("<div class='flag'>I'm the new one.</div>");

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div class="h1" data-id="1">Teachers <span class="add" data-id="US01">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher? <span class="add" data-id="US02">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>
        <br>
    <div class="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants <span class="add" data-id="US10">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town? <span class="add" data-id="US20">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="flag">Flag</div>
    <div class="edit">Edit</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#container").find('.flag, .edit, .delete').remove();
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) says you can pass the selector as an argument.

Comment: @Itay yest but the selector is used to filter the set of matched elements, not select descendants

Comment: +1 You're right. Another option would be `$("#container div").remove('.flag, .edit, .delete');`

Comment: What is when I have `<span class="flag"></span>`

Comment: The OP specifically says `divs`

Comment: A `span` or `div` with those classes. All need to go. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also :

```
$("#container .flag, #container .edit, #container .delete")
.remove();
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$("#container div").remove('.flag, .edit, .delete');`? Or `$("#container .flag, #container .edit, #container .delete").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem would be this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        $("#container .flag").add("#container .edit").add("#container .delete").remove();
        $(this).parent("div").after("<div class='flag'>I'm the new one.</div>");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3qLQz/1/